# Ubuntu Mate 16.04 doesn't ask for pairing code to connect Apple Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, 16.04, apple

I have a Linux Ubuntu Mate 16.04 on an Intel NUC i5 NUC5i5RYK.

I had problems with headphones jack, just after 1 month was been purchased, and sent it to warranty, Intel changed it for a new one.

Now, I can' connect my Apple Keyboard via bluetooth: Ubuntu doesn't ask for pairing ping.

**I can** connect my Apple Magic Mouse, but **not** my Apple Keyboard.

I have researched `hcitool` and `bluetoothctl` without success

Before sending it to warranty, I connected the Apple keyboard, now I can't because I can't type the pairing ping

What can I do? remove the bluetooth manager and reinstall it?

Thanks a lot, I have been investigating it for a week, my last option is to buy another keyboard.

I'm not going to use Magic mouse with ubuntu, it disconnects periodically...each 10 minutes (+-) , but the keyboard worked successfully

Answer (score 2):

Still without a solution I can't get it wroking.

These are the last actions I did:

1. I changed the name of keyabord connected on a Mac
2. Remove the file `/etc/bluetooth/hcid.conf` which contains information about the old name keyboard, something like: `auth enable` and `encrypt enable`
3. Assigned (Or I think so) permisions to my user to bluetooth services:   `sudo usermod -G bluetooth -a albert`

I don't know which one of these actions is the winner, but I hope can help someone, to avoid stay so long for fixing it

**23/05/2016**

After that, I had problems when connecting at startup. I have lost connection to keyboard, and so now, the problem persists

**21/05/2016**

**Solved**:

folowing [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=165504) instruccions, I did:

```
# bluetoothctl -a 

[bluetooth]# pair 10:9A:DD:9C:3D:DA
Attempting to pair with 10:9A:DD:9C:3D:DA
[CHG] Device 10:9A:DD:9C:3D:DA Connected: yes
[agent] PIN code: 882876

[bluetooth]# trust 10:9A:DD:9C:3D:DA
Changing 10:9A:DD:9C:3D:DA trust succeeded

connect <address>
```

And with this way, in terminal, asked the pin number to me.

To reconnect the keyboard, each time I startup the PC, first turn on PC, and then press the side power button, and wait for 5 - 10 seconds. Now seems to be more stable

---

**12-12-2016** . another episode in my AppleKeyboard life:

The same as I explained above, but

1- With Networking disabled

2- **without asking the pin number** to me, I typed the pin number "blind" when I see "Attempting to connect to ..."

Comment: I have the same problem on Ubuntu 16.10. As long as I pair apple magic keyboard A1644, a crash occurs. GDBus.Error:org.bluez.Error.ConnectionAttemptFailed: Page Timeout. In the directory you mentioned above "/etc/bluetooth", there is not a file named "hcid.conf". I don't know what I missed, could you help me? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

just to improve a tad the answer here everything worked except I had to type

```
[bluetooth]# scan on
```

just after

```
# bluetoothctl -a
```

And then I followed through everything else and I could pair my Apple Keyboard.

Cheers!

Comment: should probably be a comment on the other answer

Answer (score 0):

**Final solution**

After years without having a clear solution, I've realized that the connection happens when I access to the `Bluetooth Drvices` screen, and here, **without touch the keyboard wait that keyboard disconnect and reconnect alone**. this happens in 20 seconds aprox. but, very important: **do not touch the keyboard during this process**

When access to this screen, can pulse the keyboard power button to provoke this process, but only 1 time at the begining, then have to wait.

[image]